# Creating an animation of radio waves

Tags: animation

I have never used Blender, but I need to make an animation of electromagnetic waves for my project, I have a 3D model of a radio and I need to make radio waves emanate from the antenna. The animation should be like this gif:

[[image]]

Comment: Do you want this visualized in 3D, or 2D as illustrated?

Comment: I think 3D visualization would be better

Comment: Hmm .. if you can scrabble together any maths or a reference defining the field illustrated by the gif, that would help folks offer you an answer, here..

Answer (score 2):

## Radio Waves in Blender with Geometry Nodes

The form can be thought as ripples on the surface of a lake. Your reference gif is like a topographic map of such ripples. there is also a “shadow” cast in the ripples from the shape of the antenna.

We can model this form in geometry nodes.

[image: radio waves]

### Ripple Height Map

We'll start out by creating a height map of the wave form.

Use a *Wave Texture* node to model the rings of the ripple. The topographical lines in your reference are close together in the valleys, this means that the waves are more like a series of humps rather than a proper wave. we can use a *Map Range* and *Absolute* node to achieve this.

We wire up the *Phase Offset* to the scene time to animate the waves.

We then multiply the ripples by the "shadow" from the antenna. The math for the shadow can be summarized as `abs(sin(arctan2(x, y)))`

[image: radio waves height map nodes]

We could pause here and use this height map to displace a surface to get a simple visualization of the wave form:

[image]

but let’s keep going to get the topographical representation…

### Topographical Lines Mesh

The topo lines will be made by creating a stack of grids, deleting the faces that are above the height map of the wave form, isolating the boundary edges of the remaining geometry.

[image: topo lines nodes]

This technique is inspired by [this video by Chong 3D](https://youtu.be/WTQ7mgGF1zE?si=zehoXebJiPhCEewz)

### Smooth the Lines

At this point the lines will look stepped, we'll add a smooth modifier to the stack:

[image: smooth modifier]

### Convert to Curves and Finish up

[image: radio waves topo]

Add another *Geometry Nodes* modifier after the *Smooth* modifier. Use a simple network to convert the topo mesh lines into curves. then give them thickness with the *Curve to Mesh* node. Lastly, apply your desired material.

[image: to curves back to mesh]

Comment: W...ow :) .. ..