Animate a Circle Radius without Enlarging Border / Mimic Ripples / Concentric Circles
I am trying to make an animation to mimic a sound wave rippling through the air. The thing is I don't think I can use the wave modifier because I want the wave to be visible but the rest of the area to be transparent. I have played around with scaling various shapes but I don't want the "edge" to scale up as the circle gets larger.
I did experiment with using a shape key to modify the value of the edge as the circle gets bigger but my results didn't look great.

I've added a basic drawing to show what I'd like to accomplish (although it would be animated so only one circle band would appear at a time.)
Any tips / advice on how to accomplish this would be great.
Thanks
Rich

Maybe you could modify your title so that users can understand that you want to mimic ripples/concentric circles. As it is, it sounds very specific and partly unclear.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/304686/35559 .. or for a shader contour .. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212767/35559 ..


Create a curve circle
Add a shapekey on the curve circle.
Keyframe the shapekey influence (e.g. 0 > 1)
Duplicate the object and shift the keys in the timeline.



Thanks, I'll give this a shot and report back.

Thank you so much!!! I got the effect I needed.

Geometry nodes comes handy in cases where you want to animate a parameter (such as Radius) and not just scale the full object.
Replicate the arcs in geometry nodes and parametrize Radius, offset distance between arcs and thickness, then animate at will.


Thanks, I'll give this a shot and report back.
